# Тьюторіал чи туторіал?

Tags: іншомовні-слова

За правописом:

> знак м’якшення (ь) у словах іншомовного походження пишеться після
>   приголосних д, т, з, с, л, н перед я, ю, є, ї, йо

[Правопис, параграф 93](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm)

Отже має бути тьюторіал.

Але в мережі частіше трапляються контексти з **туторіалом**. Що це - незнання правила чи вмотивована зміна орфограми в слові?

> [Перекладаємо](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/tutorial) слово туторіал
>
> [Туторіал](http://netiquette.in.ua/2018/05/19/%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D1%8F%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%86%D1%96-%D1%87%D0%B0/) як розібратися у Facebook? Частина друга.
>
> [онлайн](http://www.vitaliypodoba.com/2015/06/webdev-howto/) курси і туторіали наведені раніше в даній статті

Чи англійська вимова відповідає саме звучанню **туторіал**?

Answer (score 6):

Ви, мені здається, не до кінця правильно інтерпретуєте наведене правило правопису. Воно не каже, що якщо стоїть *т*, то після нього обов'язково треба писати *ью* (*ья*, *ьє* тощо). Навіть у наступному пункті того ж правила написано: «Знак м’якшення не пишеться перед *я*, *ю*, коли вони позначають сполучення пом’якшеного приголосного з *а*, *у*: *мадя́р*, *малярі́я*; *дю́на*, *ілю́зія*, *нюа́нс*, *тю́бик*, *тюль*; *Аля́ска*, *Дюма́*, *Сю*».

Тобто фактично річ така:

- якщо воно звучить як [т'йу] чи [тйу] — то треба писати *тью*, наприклад, *Метью* **(але не *тʼю* — не  *Метʼю*)**;
- якщо воно звучить як [т'у] — то треба писати *тю*, наприклад, *тюбик*;
- якщо воно звучить як [ту] — то треба писати *ту*, наприклад, *турист*.

Тобто немає обмежень окрім заборони на *тʼю*, всі три інші варіанти можливі: *ту*, *тю*, *тью* — залежно від звучання. (Причому варіант *тью* статистично найрідкіший.)

Причому звучання, мені здається, варто зважати радше запозичене, а не оригінальне. Бо часто так трапляється, що слово, яке в оригіналі звучить по-одному, після адаптації іншою мовою починає звучати по-іншому. Хоча тут я можу помилятися.

Якщо ж усе-таки розглядати оригінальне англійське звучання, то у [Англійському Вікісловнику](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tutorial#Pronunciation) ми бачимо, що можливі два варіанти звучання: /tjuːˈtɔːɹɪəl/ (тобто [тйу…]) і /tuwˈtɔɹijəɫ/ (тобто [ту…]) — відповідно, обидва варіанти: *тью* і *ту* теоретично можливі. Причому справа ускладнюється тим, що в англійській мові немає як таких твердого [т] і м'якого [т'] — лише щось проміжне (за МФА: не [ t̪ ] і не [ tʲ ]), тому і проти варіанту *тю* мені теж теоретично нема чим заперечити.

Це слово не словникове, тому:

- я не впевнений, що воно взагалі доречне у багатьох стилях (зокрема офіційному);
- писати його можуть по-всякому (я б схилявся просто до найпоширеніших варіантів написання).

Comment: дякую за змістовну відповідь, а окремо за думку, що варто зважати на вимову запозичення, це цікава тема :) виникає додаткове питання: чи написання "туторіал" виникло через те, що мовці справді сприймають саме таке звучання англійського слова? чи це така собі  фонематична калька? транскодування?